# Cochran's Theorem - Lemma involving symmetric idempotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, probability-distributions

I am writing notes for a reading class and I've decided to add a proof of Cochran's theorem in order to show that a statistic is $\chi^2$. I am struggling for the proof of a particular lemma but the rest is just peachy.

Lemma: Let $A$ be a real real symmetric idempotent matrix of order $n$ with rank $r$. Suppose $A=A_1+\cdots+A_k$ with rank $A_i = r_i$ and $A_i$ symmetric. Additionally, $r_1+\cdots+r_k=r$.
Then each $A_i$ is idempotent.

I've been really struggling with this. It seems fairly obvious that $A_i$ gives an orthogonal decomposition of $A$. I've tried a lot of methods, looking at $A$'s and $A_i'$s spectral decomposition so I can show that the eigenvalues of $A_i$ must be $1$. Tried showing that $A_iA_j =0$ for $i$ not equal to $j$.

Answer (score 3):

The ranks of the matrices are the dimensions of their column spaces. Since the ranks of the $A_i$ add up to the rank of $A$, the column space $V$ of $A$ must be the direct sum of the column spaces $V_i$ of the $A_i$. Since $A$ is idempotent, it acts as the identity on $V$, and thus in particular on the $V_i$. That is, applying $A$ to a vector $v_i$ in $V_i$ leaves that vector invariant. Since each $A_i$ only contributes a component in its column space, it follows that $A_iv_i=v_i$ and $A_jv_i=0$ for $i\ne j$. Thus each $A_i$ is the identity on its column space and zero on its complement, and thus idempotent.

It's a bit worrying that I haven't used the symmetry of the matrices. Are you sure this is necessary?

Comment: I am not certain.  In the context of statistics the $A_i$'s are quadratic forms of random variables.  I wonder if, at any rate, they are necessarily symmetric.  My linear algebra is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 1):

By decomposing each $A_j$ into $r_j$ rank one matrices (use Rank Normal Form) we can write
$A=A_1+\cdots+A_k  = \mathbf x_1\mathbf y_1^T+ \cdots +\mathbf x_r\mathbf y_r^T =  
\bigg[\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathbf x_1 & \cdots & \mathbf x_{r}
\end{array}\bigg]\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf y_1^T \\
\vdots\\ 
 \mathbf y_{r}^T
\end{bmatrix}= XY
$

$r=\text{rank}\big(A\big)=\text{rank}\big(XY\big)\leq \min\big(\text{rank}(X),\text{rank}(Y)\big)\leq \max\big(\text{rank}(X),\text{rank}(Y)\big)\leq r$
$\implies \text{X is injective (left invertible) and Y is surjective (right invertible)}$

$XY = A=A^2 = X(YX)Y\implies I_r = YX$
via left multiplication by a left inverse of $X$ and right multiplication by a right inverse of $Y$

$ I_r = YX\implies \mathbf y_i^T\mathbf x_j =0$ for $i\neq j$ and $\mathbf y_i^T\mathbf x_i =1$
$\implies A_j$ is idempotent for arbitrary $j$ as $A_j=\sum_{i=m}^{m+r_j-1}\mathbf x_i\mathbf y_i^T=\big(\sum_{i=m}^{m+r_j-1}\mathbf x_i\mathbf y_i^T\big)^2 =A_j^2$
since all 'off-diagonal' terms of $\big(\sum_{i=m}^{m+r_j-1}\mathbf x_i\mathbf y_i^T\big)^2$ are zero and each $\mathbf x_i\mathbf y_i^T$ is idempotent.

*Remark:*
None of these matrices needs to be symmetric and the result holds over any field.