# Problem on idempotent linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Hello guys I have been trying the following problem:

> Let $V$ a finite dimensional vector space, let R,S,T: V $\rightarrow $ V linear transformations such that $R^{2}=R$, $S^{2}=S$, $T^{2}=T$ and $R+S+T = id$.
> Prove that $RS = 0$

What I have been able to advance in this problem is to first show that $Im(R+S) = Ker(T)$ and $R+S = id_{Ker(T)}$ then $R^{2} +RS = R \circ id_{Ker(T)} = R \circ id_{Im(R+S)}$ then $R+RS = R \circ id_{Im(R+S)} $
It would only be enough to show that $R \circ id_{Im(R+S)}  = R$
but I haven't been able to make any suggestions to solve my problem?

Comment: Something needs to be said about the characteristic of the field here.  Otherwise consider $R=S=T=I$ with $\mathbb F_2$ as the field and $RS=I\neq \mathbf 0$ which contradicts your problem statement.

Comment: @user8675309 it's right but in the case the field is $\mathbb{R}$ Or the field has infinite characteristics, would there be some way to show it ?

Comment: In the case of characteristic zero, you can  use the trace to get their ranks i.e. conclude that $\text{rank}\big(R\big)+\text{rank}\big(S\big)+\text{rank}\big(T\big)=\text{rank}\big(I\big)$ then either of the proofs here should work for you:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75990/cochrans-theorem-lemma-involving-symmetric-idempotent-matrices/